# Protocols and port numbers

Tags: port, protocols

I came across a list of all the well-known port numbers.
Corresponding to them were some protocols.
Is it that ports are defined only for protocols?
Because some of the entries corresponding to the port numbers were defined as just an application or procedure. Does it mean the same as a protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Port numbers are associated with a protocol as a matter of convention, or if a protocol's specification mandates that a particular port be used, however the vast majority of applications will run on any port: you might see HTTP servers running on ports 81 or 8080, for example.

Having well-known ports simplifies the connection process because the client doesn't need to know in-advance what port number it should use: browsers assume 80, for example, unless the URI specifies otherwise.

In comparison, consider classical FTP which uses well-known-port 21 for the command connection, which is used to send data connection port numbers to the client. If FTP made use of well-known-ports then the client could assume the data connection's port number without requesting it from the server (other reasons for custom port numbers notwithstanding).

Comment: I want to know whether application/procedure mean the same as protocol? Like for example if I consider RJE, it has port number 5 but everywhere it is defined as a procedure. Is RJE a protocol?

Comment: @timidgeek Not quite. Note that the definition if "application" varies (it can refer to a protocol in certain cases). Generally a protocol is a language that multiple prograns can speak: like how HTTP is spoken by Chrome, IE, Apache and IIS. However I've never heard of a protocol referred to as a "procedure", can you please share a link that makes that definition?

Comment: I referred to Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_job_entry

So, is RJE a protocol or not?

Comment: @timidgeek It is neither. The Wikipedia page describes it as an abstract class of operations. That the "List of TCP and UDP ports" page links to it for Port 5 is probably an oversight. It might be a reference to NETRJS however NETRJS uses ports 71-75.

Answer (score 0):

TCP and UDP uses Port numbers to communicate with the upper layers, this is what keeps track of the conversations crossing the network.
Originating port numbers are dynamically assigned by the sending host.
these port numbers identify the sending and destination applications on a TCP segment.
Port numbers below 1024 are well known port numbers.
Ex: Telnet - 23, SSH - 22, SMTP - 25, HTTP - 80, HTTPS - 443, FTP - 20,21, POP3 - 110